# Are android questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As I read [Android wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) all I found is that:

1. It is [Linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org)(who would suspect ;) )
2. "nor does it support the full set of standard GNU libraries" without mentioning if it is POSIX compatible

I would say they are on topic (Linux & possibly Linux) but what is your opinion?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know much about Android devices, but I would say questions about the underlying *nix operating system belong here. Questions about programming for it probably belong on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), and questions about the devices themselves probably belong on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Android runs a Linux kernel but little else (most of the OS is written in Java, with an API extending the Java standard library, totally unrelated to the Unix/POSIX API). The N810 and friends run an actual Linux distribution, that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @Gilles True. I actually have an Android phone now, so I'm less confused about the amount of Linux involved

Comment: "What video players are there" questions definitely do not belong on Android Enthusiasts. They're broad, open-ended, attract spam, have no correct answer, and go out of date very quickly. Also, no questions about the N810 belong on Android Enthusiasts because it isn't an Android device. The edit that introduced that was wrong.

Comment: @DanHulme I've removed the part about the N810 since it's irrelevant (the N810 doesn't run Android, it runs a Linux distribution (derived from Debian)) and seems to have been put there by mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about the Android kernel, which is a Linux kernel (not the mainline tree, but still ~99.9% Linux), are definitely on-topic here. Questions about using unix tools such as Busybox, or about compiling unix programs, might be considered on topic, for the same reason that shell scripting is on-topic even if you're running the script on [Cygwin](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/cygwin-on-topic). But general Android usage questions are very far from anything unix-like. Ask on [**Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange**](https://android.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

[It's a unix](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/offtopic-a-stance-programming-servers-cross-platform-applications) so why not? but as Michael says there may be better places to ask depending on your question.

Comment: Not really, there's very little unixy in Android outside the kernel.