# Is it ok to ask bash language questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I find myself asking more and more questions that might overlap with SO.

Where should I ask `bash` questions that focus more on the bash language than they do on unix? Here or on SO?

Comment: See also: [Shell scripting on-topic?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84/shell-scripting-on-topic)

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, `bash` is not a programmer language like `C` or `Java`. It is more an administrator language and more administrators are the experts of `bash`.

Of course you can write complex applications with `bash`, but most of the time, you use it to manage the execution and behavior of other programs. You are also not calling functions with `bash`, you are executing programs/builtins which you are calling the same way while browsing your shell ;)

Many answers of questions posted here will be a `bash` script. If we move all `bash` questions to SO and every second answer is a bash script, everybody will confuse.

My suggestion: Allow `bash` questions, but cut off other scripting languages

Comment: That's a good distinction. "How do I do X in bash?" I would leave here, as very often a bash script is not the best way (you can usually just chain utils together to pull it off). "How do I do X in a bash script?" I consider programming, but am willing to leave here if people want

Comment: Also, I suspect you meant `bash` the first time you said `java` in the second paragraph :)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: changed it ;)

Comment: @krissi I assume by "other scripting languages" you mean *non unix shell* because technically `zsh`, etc, is another scripting language.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Yes, I used `bash` as synonym for all these unix shell languages ;)

Comment: @Michael: I thought shell scripting *was* how you chained utils together?

Comment: @SamB I meant piping tools together in the shell itself, e.g. `ls | sort | head -n10`

Comment: @Michael: oh, I hadn't realized there was a distinction :-)

Comment: @SamB There probably isn't much of one. We ended up making shell scripting on topic anyway (it even ended up with a bullet in the [faq](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) ), so it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 3):

If it's anything you would type into a terminal it definitely belongs here. Questions about entire shell scripts are fuzzy; they are technically programming and I would personally ask them on SO, but I'm not sure we need to close them if people choose to ask them here. When we're out of beta we can talk about potentially migrating them to SO

Answer (score 2):

[I think it's Unix](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/offtopic-a-stance-programming-servers-cross-platform-applications). In certain cases you might get better/faster answers on StackOverflow but no reason you can't ask here, the shell is one of the most important features of Unix systems.