# Non Standard CLI tools - A ruby tool question

Tags: discussion, scope

[An earlier related question on meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/is-it-on-or-off-topic-when-unix-linux-is-only-ancillary-to-the-question). [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/how-do-i-make-the-1-9-2-ruby-string-point-to-the-final-release-with-rvm) was asked and ultimately answered on SO. This tool is is probably mostly used by Ruby programmers to test on multiple versions, and maybe slightly used by Sys Admin's to run different apps on different versions. I felt it belonged more on SO (and got a faster answer there) my question is should this type of question be closed as offtopic ( *or migrated* )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it is off-topic and should be closed/migrated to SO. While possibly 'got faster response' is not necessary rule of thumb (SO is larger) I'd say it would be faster resplied there even if the sizes of sites were equal - because it is more connected with programming then Unix&Linux.