# "What jobs are out there?" -- are career questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, top-7

This comes from the question [what jobs are out there for NIX nerds?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/what-jobs-are-out-there-for-nix-nerds). I personally think this is probably off-topic, and it has two close votes already, but it also has three upvotes so I wanted to ask here

I think this falls under [Is it On or Off Topic When Unix/Linux is Only Ancillary to the Question?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/is-it-on-or-off-topic-when-unix-linux-is-only-ancillary-to-the-question); the base question is "What jobs are out there", and then "*nix" is inserted into the question to make it on-topic. SO handles this by having a bullet in [their FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) that says questions are on-topic if they discuss "matters that are *unique* to the programming profession". We don't currently cover this sort of thing in the FAQ, but it can be added after we decide

Thoughts?

Comment: What's the [meta-tag:top-7] tag on this question for?

Comment: Predates me, but maybe a reference to https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/10/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, comparing with [AU](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/top-7) seems to confirm that

Answer (score 10):

I would say that they are off-topic/not precise:

1. The full answer is too specific (what relevant education have the person, what experience)
2. The generic answer is useless as much depends on time, location, education or experience

A 16-year-old with no formal experience and 30-year-old from a good university with relevant diploma + brilliant resume of 7 years of continuous experience both may be "nix geeks" but the career options are somehow different. The 7 years can be done hacking kernel, writing servers, administrating them etc. - each having different career choices.

Besides - there is [Careers site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Agrred... what else is Carreers for, if not this?

Comment: @gabe.: Careers is for people who want a job now, and these questions are for people who want a job later (i.e. *what skillz do me need*).

Comment: As for the 1st point, that is simply a matter of question quality, and such requirement for specifics isn't limited to just Careers. As for the 2nd point, the answer could be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 6):

You can ask questions about a unix [*programming* career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) on [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). (As you can tell from the name, this site doesn't discuss sysadmin careers.) Be sure to first read their [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), in particular the [section on career advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#link-can-i-ask-career-advice-questions). In particular, make sure you have the right balance between a too-general question (“How can I get a unix-related job?”) and a [too-personal question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster/590#590) (“What should I do with my career now?”).

Answer (score 4):

I think the question wouldn't have any answer at all "if you take Unix/Linux out of it". Personally I still want to know the answer, and it may be good in case somebody comes to our site wondering "Should I learn Linux?"

It is not stated in the FAQ whether unix.stackexchange.com is technical, but I think it can be taken for granted that most questions will be. A few non-technical questions won't have much impact on the site, while they can bring viewers who may become new users. They are not entirely off-topic (you can even say they are on-topic), and there won't be many of them anyway.

So, I'd like to keep this question open :)

Comment: I'm fine with saying they're on-topic, but I hate the argument that "they're ok because they're rare" -- either they're on-topic or they're not, it should never be "they're off-topic but we'll let it go this time"

Comment: how about "they are on-topic and they are rare"?