# Are career questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“What jobs are out there?” — are career questions on-topic?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/what-jobs-are-out-there-are-career-questions-on-topic)

Do we want career-related questions here? They're not liked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (but there's [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)); I don't know if [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) has a consensus.

**NOTE**: We currently [have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3438/688) [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9050/688).