# Delete the /career tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [career](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag has only 9 questions and most of them are closed (7 out of 9) because they are off-topic. Career questions belong to the Workplace Stack Exchange. Should we delete this tag to not encourage users to post off-topic questions?

Comment: [previously](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/what-jobs-are-out-there-are-career-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 13):

The questions that have the tag are correctly tagged, they are about careers. So don't edit the questions to remove the tag.

Most of the questions with this tag are already closed. If we decide we don't want career-related questions, then we should finish the job: close and delete the undesirable questions. Once there are no non-deleted questions with the tag, the tag will disappear from the list.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as far as I'm concerned. I don't see any point in [career](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and can't really imagine any question that would be on topic and fit that tag.

Unless anyone objects, we can just remove the tag from those 9 questions and let it disappear from the site.

Comment: Some posts will become [tag:untagged]. What do we do about those?

Comment: @muru I don't think so, actually. the only untagged questions are all historical, off topic ones that are fine to remain untagged. If there were any questions tagged with only "career", they have already been retagged.

Comment: Maybe a caching issue, but: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249252/what-is-the-difference-between-lfcs-and-lpic, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/what-jobs-are-out-there-for-nix-geeks, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2341/shell-script-certification

Comment: @muru eeek! Sorry, I got confused and was looking at [tag:careers] instead of [tag:career].

Comment: @muru We don't remove the tag by editing the questions, but by deleting them.

Comment: @Gilles O.o I didn't edit any of the questions involved.